# Key column X doesn't exist in table while trying to drop X from table

Tags: mariadb, alter-table

I need some help. I'm trying to run some migrations scripts on a NEW docker instance (the old one and local works fine). Mariadb, Innodb engine.

I have a migrations like this:

```
ALTER TABLE userinfo DROP COLUMN barcode
```

that gives me error:
StatementEnd Error Code: 1072. Key column 'barcode' doesn't exist in table

The column exist! This is my SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE userinfo (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  barcode varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  store_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY store_id_barcode_UNIQUE (`store_id`,`barcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I tried something like `ALTER TABLE userinfo ADD KEY "barcode" ("barcode")` but the DROP statement still does not work.

P.S. i removed a lot of columns from the CREATE statement or this thread would be too long to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [ALTER TABLE/DROP COLUMN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#drop-column):

> MariaDB starting with 10.2.8
> Dropping a column that is part of a
> multi-column UNIQUE constraint is not permitted...

First, drop the unique key in which `barcode` is part of and then you will be able to drop it:

```
ALTER TABLE userinfo DROP KEY store_id_barcode_UNIQUE;
ALTER TABLE userinfo DROP COLUMN barcode;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RFFRfzOs).

Comment: It _might_ work to combine those into a single ALTER statement (with the DROP KEY first).